# MySQL Collation Mixture Error When Selecting View

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, collation

I've been fighting the collation and character set battle for a while now, and of course just when I thought I was winning, I was stumped by a new issue. All of my tables and rows and the database itself are in the same collation (utf8_unicode_ci)m but for some reason, half of my views work and the other half get this error:

> Error Code: 1267. Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT)
>   and (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='

Can anyone shed some light as to why I'm getting this error and how to fix it? I attempted to alter the view with Workbench, but a popup shows with he same error message when I try to do so, which is quite frustrating.

Comment: It seems i have the same issue. Also i get this error only when using nodejs mysql2 library when i try to use this from mysqlworkbench everything works just fine. Also when i copy the select statement from the view into the query (in nodejs) it works fine but when i `select * from view` it throws the error.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the console to check on the view (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-create-view.html):

```
SHOW CREATE VIEW ....
```

And you should check the collation set for the fields in the view.

Something tells me that you've created a database with one collation, then continued importing or creating views and datatables in another, and then started changing collation for the existing database and view one by one. While this surely looks rather entertaining, I would recommend recreating the database overall (from the scripts) with the correct collation and character.

Comment: same error from the terminal with `show create view \`database\`.\`view\`;` with error `ERROR 1267 (HY000): Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='` :(

Comment: Please provide output for the following query:

    `SELECT TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, COLLATION_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`